What is the difference between tcp fast open and carrying data with the second ACK?
I've learned that you can carry data with the second ACK during a tcp handshake, and it feels a little redundant to have a separate feature to do two way handshake when you can practically do it already.
What are the benefits of using a cookie instead of simply the sequence number if it actually makes a difference?

Without TCP fast open, the client can send data with the second packet, ie:
> SYN
< SYN+ACK
> ACK+data
With TCP fast open, both the client and the server can send data with the first packet. To prevent attacks using IP spoofing in this case, a TFO cookie established in a previous connection needs to be provided by the client:
> SYN+cookie+data
< SYN+ACK+data

This particular use case is too narrow to meet up with what the proposal says "performance needs of today's Web applications", isn't it?

And amplification attack still exist because server send data before the cookie could be verified.

@GasaiMaple: I've updated the answer to make clear that the  TFO cookie needs to be provided, so that IP spoofing is not possible. And that also the client can send data already in the first packet, thus making all but the initial TCP handshake faster (basically 0-RTT, i.e. immediately sending data).

How would that prevent IP spoofing? I can still fake a random cookie since the server don't have any knowledge about the authentic client isn't it?

@GasaiMaple: The cookie is issued by the server in a previous connection. The client cannot fake it since the server will check that it has actually issued this cookie.
